# perl strip character from hash key string

Tags: perl

below is my hash.

```
my %HoA= (
HU1.2.3.4X => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
HU1.2.3.4 => [ 'apple', 'oranges', 'grapes', ],
PU1000.2.003.4X => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
FA1.200.3.4 => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', ],
FA1.200.3.4X => [ 'between' ],
OT100.2.30.4 => [ 'morpheus, lord of dreams' ],
);
```

I need to strip off "X" from the end of my key, so if I strip of "X" from HU1.2.3.4X I need to have key value HU1.2.3.4 for later printing of key/value in my script.

Any help on this please. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
*Edited my hash with some more key/values. for example*

```
FA1.200.3.4 => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', ],
FA1.200.3.4X => [ 'between' ],
```

Keys here are **FA1.200.3.4 and FA1.200.3.4X** - Ideally both the keys are same identifier with "X" appended in later key. So can we handle like stripping X from last and map the values FA1.200.3.4 and FA1.200.3.4X in single key/value

FA1.200.3.4 => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', 'between'],

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your first thought might be to iterate over the hash (using `keys()` or `each()`) deleting keys that end in 'X' and replacing them with a stripped version. This is a bad idea as you shouldn't change a hash whilst you are iterating over it. So don't do that.

The best approach is to write the changed key/value pairs to a new hash. But it's completely possible to write those new pairs back into your original hash - like this:

```
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

my %HoA = (
  'HU1.2.3.4X' => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
  'PU1000.2.003.4X' => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
  'FA1.200.3.4' => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', ],
  'OT100.2.30.4' => [ 'morpheus, lord of dreams' ],
);

%HoA = map { my $v = $HoA{$_}; s/X$//; $_ => $v } keys %HoA;

say Dumper \%HoA;
```

Comment: your post is nice short :) Thanks for this solution with "map".

Comment: @DaveCross: Your caution is appropriate for `while`/`each`, but `keys` and `values` both generate a static list and iterate over that, so the approach is safe. If you wish to make absolutely sure of this then of course you may write `my @keys = keys %HoA` and iterate over that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply delete each element and add it back with `X` removed from the key

This example is inefficient in that it also removes and replaces unchanged elements whose keys *don't* end with `X`, but as a one-time operation this will be insignificant unless your hashis enormous

I have used `Data::Dumper` only to display the resulting data structure. Any mention of `Data::Dumper` may be removed from your final code

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse  = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

my %HoA = (
    'HU1.2.3.4X'      => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
    'PU1000.2.003.4X' => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
    'FA1.200.3.4'     => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', ],
    'OT100.2.30.4'    => [ 'morpheus, lord of dreams', ],
);

$HoA{ s/X\z//r } = delete $HoA{$_} for keys %HoA;

print Dumper \%HoA;
```

#### output

```
{
    'OT100.2.30.4' => [
        'morpheus, lord of dreams'
    ],
    'PU1000.2.003.4' => [
        'hamnet',
        'shakespeare',
        'robyn'
    ],
    'FA1.200.3.4' => [
        'oberon',
        'titania',
        'puck'
    ],
    'HU1.2.3.4' => [
        'hamnet',
        'shakespeare',
        'robyn'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use function which takes transformation callback as an argument,

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %HoA = (
  'HU1.2.3.4X' => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
  'PU1000.2.003.4X' => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
  'FA1.200.3.4' => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', ],
  'OT100.2.30.4' => [ 'morpheus, lord of dreams' ],
);

sub ren_hkeys {
    my ($href, $f) = @_;
    my @arr  = keys %$href;
    @$href{ map $f->(), @arr } = delete @$href{ @arr };
}
ren_hkeys(\%HoA, sub{ s/X$//r });

print Dumper \%HoA;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'OT100.2.30.4' => [
                          'morpheus, lord of dreams'
                        ],
      'FA1.200.3.4' => [
                         'oberon',
                         'titania',
                         'puck'
                       ],
      'HU1.2.3.4' => [
                       'hamnet',
                       'shakespeare',
                       'robyn'
                     ],
      'PU1000.2.003.4' => [
                            'hamnet',
                            'shakespeare',
                            'robyn'
                          ]
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to make this in-place. You will have to iterate over keys, and populate a new hash table with the modified/fixed keys.

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to create a new hash with your new keys like the following code snippet:

```
my %HoA= (
"HU1.2.3.4X" => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
"PU1000.2.003.4X" => [ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ],
"FA1.200.3.4" => [ 'oberon', 'titania', 'puck', ],
"OT100.2.30.4" => [ 'morpheus, lord of dreams' ],
);

my %HoA_new;

foreach my $key( keys %HoA) {
 if( $key =~ m/.*?X$/) {
    # save the value
    my $value = $HoA{$key};

    # split the key
    $key =~ s/(.*?)X$//g;

    # save value with new key
    $HoA_new{$1} = $value;
 } else {
     $HoA_new{$key} = $HoA{$key};
 }
}

print Dumper(\%HoA_new);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the guidance and suggestions. I have edited my questions. If possible please share your thoughts. Thanks.